# Merge HTML, CSS, JS and Assets to one file

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, file

I'm currently building a little experiment.

It's about having some sort of "emulator" written in C# that can run some "ROMs" that are programmed in HTML ( CSS, JS, .. ).

To build there ROMs, I've programmed a little "compiler" that is using my JS based game engine and it's editor to pack the game / application into a single file ( the "ROM" ) that is basically just an encrypted ( or plain ) JSON file that contains the full HTML code ( in one of its attributes ), except that linked files are directly written into it.

---

```
<script src="./script/main.js"></script>
```

will turn into:

```
<script> ...code... </script>
```

and the same with CSS.

---

Images will be turned into Base64 String

```
<img src="http://www.img.com/img.png"/>
```

becomes

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, R0lGODlhmwD....."/>
```

---

My problem is, to include font files into the CSS or HTML file.

So maybe something like this

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v10/K88pR3goAWT7BTt32Z01m1tXRa8TVwTICgirnJhmVJw.woff2) format('woff2');
}
```

becomes

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url( ...magic... ) format('woff2');
}
```

---

Does anybody know if this is possible, and if so, how I can implement that functionality ?

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: I think you're essentially [asking for this](http://sosweetcreative.com/2613/font-face-and-base64-data-uri)?

Comment: @JamesThorpe was literally just writing that. beat me by seconds

Comment: Oh well yeah, I could have imagine that. thank you guys.

Comment: I am currently looking for a tool that does what you describe, i.e. automatically put several sources into one html file. Do you have a solution that you can share?

Comment: @mzuba https://github.com/remy/inliner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should works:

```
@font-face{
 font-family: 'Open Sans';
 src: url(data:font/ttf;base64,AAEA… ) format('truetype');
}
```

Found here: http://blog.patdavid.net/2012/08/embedding-fonts-with-css-and-base64.html

Comment: Thank you for that. I didn't except the answer for this to be that simple :) Now I feel stupid,